# php objects, how to access a simplexmlelement

Tags: php

I have the following object:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#337 (1) { [0]=> string(4) "1001" }
```

But I can't seem to access it using [0] or even not using foreach($value as $obj=>$objvalue)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try casting it to string: `(string)$element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) implements [Traversable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), which means you could use `foreach` to loop it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$objectarray = get_object_vars(object(SimpleXMLElement));
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the SimpleXMLElement [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) I found this example (the example XML file is on the top of the page of the link):

```
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* For each <character> node, we echo a separate <name>. */
foreach ($movies->movie->characters->character as $character) {
   echo $character->name, ' played by ', $character->actor, PHP_EOL;
}
```

And I found this function to transform the XML object to an array, maybe that's easier to use?:

```
    function toArray($xml) { //$xml is of type SimpleXMLElement 
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), TRUE);

        foreach ( array_slice($array, 0) as $key => $value ) {
            if ( empty($value) ) $array[$key] = NULL;
            elseif ( is_array($value) ) $array[$key] = toArray($value);
        }

        return $array;
    }
```